# Scala transform String to StringOps

Tags: string, scala

Scala seems to transform objects of type String to StringOps. How is this done? I.e. how and when does Scala transform an object of String to StringOps?

Comment: This is not a programming question, please narrow down to some issue, else it couldl get closed.

Comment: It actually is a programming question. You just should know Scala to understand it. (Well, no wonder, the question was tagged with "scala" after all.)

Comment: This question is not "too broad".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an implicit conversion defined from `String` to `StringOps` in `Predef.scala`. https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/a24ca7fa617cabada82c43d2d6ac354db698d181/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L308. This converts a `String` instance to a `StringOps` instance if you call method from `StringOps` class on a `String`.

Comment: That by the way means that StringOps kicks in only when you call it. Otherwise the String is left to be String, no CPU time spent on any transformations.

Comment: Ok! Got it, thanks! I assume it's the same for all *Ops classes, like ArrayOps etc.